# Single linked list insertion.

Tags: c

This is how I have defined my node:

```
struct node
{
    char familyName[1023];   
    char firstName[1023];
    char position;
    int value;
    struct node *next; // points to the next node in list
} Node;
```

I need to make the insert function that would check for the duplicate last name and just add the player based on the last name (disregarding the first name). Also, I have to sort the players based on their position, so all the goalies will be first and then the defenders.

This is how I have started, but I seem to be stuck and unsure of what to do. Please help.

```
struct Node* insert (struct Node *head)
{
    struct Node *temp;

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        head=(struct Node *)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        if(head==NULL)
        {
            printf("Error! memory is not available\n");
            exit(0);
        }
    }
        printf("  family name: ");
        safegets(head->familyName, MAX_LENGTH+1);

        printf("  first name: ");
        safegets(head->firstName, MAX_LENGTH+1);

        printf("  position: ");
        scanf("%c", &(head->position));
        getchar();

        printf("  value: ");
        scanf("%d", &(head->value));
        getchar();
}
```

However, i think I am not doing it correctly and should have another node, which will store the the family name first name position and value and then compare and then add it to the head. Please help.

Comment: Homework? If so, please use the tag.

Comment: The function you mention has only the code to get input from the user. You don't seem to have the code that does the checking for the duplicate user here. Please show that code and that will be helpful in answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite  a few things you have to consider.
At first is a single linked list a decent datastructure of things you know in advance? 
You know that there just can be so many players in each team. And  you do not have a prefabricated search or sort function availalbe in Standard C. And in fact you are "looking" in at least two fields, the name field and the position field.

If you can use external libraries, have a look at glib http://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.30/glib-Doubly-Linked-Lists.html eg. has  functions for inserting into an ordered list. That  would be quite handy here.

The next small tip: Don's use scanf for getting input of the user, better use a a combination out of fgets and sscanf.

Now to you code. It does not show any try to keep an order in the list.  So you either have to run the list on every insertion. And because it is a single linked list  you need at least to check the  current element name and the following element name.

Assume you have Adam -> Ben  in you list and you want to add Anton
then you have to check the first name Adam < Anton and the
second name and there you find Anton < Ben. So you have to insert between Adam and Ben.

For that you need to break the linked list (pseudo code (untested))
insert_after = Adam
insert_before = Ben
newElement -> next = insert_before 
insert_after -> next = newElement....

So you have to be careful.